# Get email address from mailbox string

Tags: php, regex, email

I need to extract the email address out of this mailbox string.
I thought of `str_replace` but the display name and the email address is not static so I don’t know how to do this using regular expressions.

Example: "`My name <email@example.com>`" should result in "`email@example.com`".

Any ideas?

Thanks
Matthy

Comment: `My name <email@example.com>` is not valid; it must be `"My name" <email@example.com>` according to RFC 822.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at face value, the following will work:

```
preg_match('~<([^>]+)>~',$string,$match);
```

but i have a sneaking suspicion you need something better than that.  There are a ton of "official" email regex patterns out there, and you should be a bit more specific about the context and rules of the match.

Comment: In my app I personally use * after angle the brackets to ensure that all email address formats match even when users don't specify a title and email address

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist) to parse that address:

```
$addresses = imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist('My name <email@gmail.com>');
```

Comment: PHP saves the day with an amazing list of obscure functions. :)

Comment: Yeah, I remember the `easter_date()` answer (which is gone now) to that code golf question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the string is surrounded by `<` and `>` you can simply split out according to that.

This assumes that you will always have only one pair of `<` and `>` surrounding the string, and it will not ensure that the result is an email pattern.

Otherwise you can always read up on [email regex patterns](http://joshuakehn.com/blog/index.php/basic/view/41/When-internals-don-t-matter-it-s-time-to-split).

Answer (score -1):

or Look up regular expressions (preg_match).

something like: [^<]*<([^>]*)>;

Answer (score -1):

I'm coming from a time and from projects where Regex was to expensive for easy string extraction.

```
$s = 'My name <email@gmail.com>';
$s = substr(($s = substr($s, (strpos($s, '<')+1))), 0, strrpos($s, '>'));
```

Results in

```
email@gmail.com
```

Comment: This seems dangerous for me, since the name can probably contain "<" and ">" characters. `strrpos` instead of `strpos` will avoid this problem.