# How to extract Email & Name from Full Email text using PHP?

Tags: php, string, email

I have a string as

```
$email_string='Aslam Doctor <aslam.doctor@gmail.com>';
```

From which I want to extract Name & Email using PHP? so that I can get

```
$email='aslam.doctor@gmail.com';
$name='Aslam Doctor'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As much as people will probably recommend regular expression I'd say use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
Explode splits the string up in several substrings using any delimiter.
In this case I use ' <' as a delimiter to immediately strip the whitespace between the name and e-mail.

```
$split = explode(' <', $email_string);
$name = $split[0];
$email = rtrim($split[1], '>');
```

[rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) will trim the '>' character from the end of the string.

Answer (score 6):

Using `explode` + `list`:

```
$email_string = 'Aslam Doctor <aslam.doctor@gmail.com>';
list($name, $email) = explode(' <', trim($email_string, '> '));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the IMAP extension, the [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist) function is all you need.

/via https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638433/204774

Answer (score 0):

text variable have one paragraph. two emails are included there. using extract_emails_from_string() function we extracts those mails from that paragraph.
preg_match_all function will return all matching strings with the regular expression from inputs.

```
function extract_emails_from_string($string){
  preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $matches);
  return $matches[0];
}


$text = "Please be sure to answer the Please arun1@email.com be sure to answer the Please be sure to answer the Please be sure to answer the Please be sure to answer the Please be sure to answer the Please be sure to answer the  arun@email.com";
$emails = extract_emails_from_string($text);
print(implode("\n", $emails));
```

Comment: Your pattern doesn't need the `i` pattern modifier if your character class contains `a-zA-Z`. The literal `.` in the character class doesn't need escaping.   `\w` is equivalent to [0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use - works for email addresses with and without the angle bracket formatting. Because we are searching from right to left, this also works for those weird instances where the name segment actually contains the `<` character:

```
$email   = 'Aslam Doctor <aslam.doctor@gmail.com>';
$address = trim(substr($email, strrpos($email, '<')), '<>');
```